# The meaning of ちっちゃなハート

Tags: translation, meaning

I understand that to say ちっちゃなハート  doesn't mean "little heart" in the "romantic" context, it actually means someone who is not brave or courageous. Would like a native speaker to shed some further light/context (or let me know if I am totally wrong). Also consider ちっちゃな心 context and meaning?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

What you are saying is neither totally correct nor totally incorrect.  It is at least partially correct.

The problem here is your use of the term "**romantic context**" because that is not a very specific context.  All kinds of topics could be covered in a romantic context, could it not?  Romance could happen to all types of people, too.

「ちっちゃなハート」 can certainly mean "little heart".  A young girl once said to me, 「アタシのちっちゃなハート、全部{ぜんぶ}〇〇[君]{くん}にあげる！♡」.  〇〇, of course, is my family name.

「ちっちゃなハート」 can also mean "**cowardly heart**".

Same goes for 「ちっちゃな心」.  What it means would entirely depend on the context.  As a general tendency, however, it is often used to refer to a "little heart" and a "***narrow mind***".  It would rarely, if ever, be used to mean a "cowardly heart".

Comment: 「ちっちゃなハート」 can also mean "chicken heart" regardless of the context except at the yakitori place where you want to order the real chicken hearts. 　That word is 「ハツ」, BTW. -- I don't get it, "chicken heart" has only one meaning and that is real chicken hearts.

Comment: @Leo I guess he meant "chicken" as in "not brave or courageous". Like someone has the heart of a chicken. Though the heart part does make it a bit weird and confusing.

Comment: It's unidiomatic in English to say 'chicken heart' to refer to a cowardly heart. It would only refer to a literal chicken heart.

Comment: Right, my point was that if he is referring to "cowardly" then it is unidiomatic to say "chicken heart". I was actually wondering if it was a waseieigo term since I've never heard/seen it before.

Comment: I think the real question here is: what is the rest of your story?!

Answer (score 0):

The usage and context of ハート vs 心 tends to be different.

- ハート → more figurative, romantic nuance, emotion, the "heart shape"
- 心 → mind, feeling, strength etc. (you wouldn't refer to the "heart shape" with this word;  it'd be unnatural)
- 心臓 → literally the muscle in your body we know as the "heart"

It might make sense to interchange ハート with 心 in some instances, but not the other way around.

ハート is less "serious," if you will, and more innocent in its figurativeness. 心 loses that nuance. Perhaps this is the biggest differentiator in your presented situation.